# How can I get the public key for ubuntu 10.04 update manager?

Tags: 11.04, update-manager

Update manager fails with a dialog box that says

```
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid Release: The following signatures  
   couldn't be verified because the public key is not available:  
   NO_PUBKEY 5126890CDCC7AFE0
```

I have tried a few "solutions" to this. The next step is always to add a key to the keyring. Whenever I try

```
~$ gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key 5126890CDCC7AFE0  
       gpg: requesting key DCC7AFE0 from hkp server pgpkeys.mit.edu  
       gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect to host gpg:  
       no valid OpenPGP data found. gpg: Total number processed: 0 

~$ gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 5126890CDCC7AFE0  
       gpg: requesting key DCC7AFE0 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com  
       gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect to host gpg:  
       no valid OpenPGP data found. gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

that, I get the error message

```
HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect to host
```

This error seems to be associated with connecting to the internet through a proxy server. However, I am connected directly to the internet.

What am I missing?

Thanks
Fred

Comment: Please tell us the commands that resulted in that error.

Comment: you can always edit your question, and then please remove those two comments :)

Comment: OK. I'm new here so I don't know the rules. It looks like you edited the question for me. Thanks. Is this OK now?

Comment: Sure, it is not so much about "rules" but about making it easy for everyone to participate, to understand the question and later on a (hopefully) sensational answer ;-)

Comment: Please accept Robie's answer if it solved your problem - we need to find good answers.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're using a PPA (personal package archive). These make packages available to you that aren't part of Ubuntu.

If you don't want this, you can disable the PPA by looking in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and/or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` for the appropriate entry, and either removing or commenting it out. Then Update Manager should work correctly again.

If you do want the PPA enabled, then the easiest way to fix the problem is to remove the entry as above, and then adding it again using the `add-apt-repository` command. This command both adds the PPA and automatically and securely retrieves and enables the correct key.

Alternatively, you can get the key from [here](http://keyserver.ubuntu.com:11371/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x5126890CDCC7AFE0). Save that (the part including and between `BEGIN PGP...` and `END PGP...`) to a file and import it using `sudo apt-key add <filename>`. But note that this method is not secure, since you are retrieving the key over an unencrypted channel.

Comment: That was incomplete and I'm trying to learn the markdown stuff. 5 minutes wasn't enough....  

Thanks, @robie. I found a file  
  
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/eclipse-team-debian-package-lucid.list  

and commented out the contents. Then update worked. I'll leave it alone for now, but I might need to fix it the next time I update the Android support in Eclipse (or whatever it came from).

Comment: It turns out that the fundamental problem was that the corporate firewall blocks port 11371.